# KVM Userspace Port I/O

Tags: c, linux, kvm

I'm currently experimenting with KVM, and trying to get US (userspace) I/O working. Currently, output (i.e. `out dx, eax`) works, and the US code can see the written value, but input (`in eax, dx`) does not seem to work - the VM doesn't receive the value written by the US code.

```
if (run->io.port == 0xface && run->io.direction == KVM_EXIT_IO_IN)
{
    printf("Port 0xface read\n");
    *(volatile uint32_t *)((uintptr_t)run + run->io.data_offset) = 0xdeadbeefu;
    continue;
}
```

`run` is a pointer to a `struct kvm_run` that was `mmap`ed earlier and has enough space (i.e. `run->io.data_offset` is a valid offset from the pointer). The `continue` statement eventually causes the VM to restart, and the code continues normally. However, when I try to get the VM's `rax` register (which should be `0xdeadbeef`), I get zero. From what I read in the docs (`kvm/Documentation/api.txt`), this is how I should be doing it. Am I missing something?

On a semi-related note, if I precede the `continue` statement with `run->io.count = run->io.count;`, the I/O is triggered again (even though `count` isn't changed). Is this expected behavior? Or am I triggering undefined behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the actual `mmap` call:

```
run = mmap(NULL, mapSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, vcpuFD, 0);
```

The `flags` parameter should be `MAP_SHARED` instead of `MAP_PRIVATE`:

```
run = mmap(NULL, mapSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, vcpuFD, 0);
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
```

The virtual machine will see the updated values when `KVM_RUN` is issued to restart it.

Comment: Note to the reader that the 5th argument to mmap for the KVM run area is not the ID of the vcpu (as implied by the code quoted in this answer), but its FD (file descriptor).

Comment: @Bogatyr good catch! This was code I'd written ages ago that I probably don't have anymore; I'll update my answer